# Adding two repos to git config, how can I automatically fetch both after a push?

Tags: git

What would be a good a way to fetch all branches (to check consistency via `branch -av` between both repos) in `[remote "all"]` after a push?  I have a fetch for both `origin` and `backup`, but it's only fetching the first.

```
[core]
        repositoryformatversion = 0
        filemode = true
        bare = false
        logallrefupdates = true
        ignorecase = true
        precomposeunicode = true
[remote "origin"]
        url = git@host:origin/repo.git
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[remote "backup"]
        url = git@host:backup/repo.git
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/backup/*
[remote "all"]
        url = git@host:origin/repo.git
        url = git@host:backup/repo.git
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/backup/*
[branch "master"]
        remote = all
        merge = refs/heads/master
```

I'm currently going the route of typing `git push all [branch]`, followed by `git fetch all` since the only fetch it's automatically grabbing is the first repo listed in `[remote "all"]` (even though I have both listed.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that for `fetch`.  (You can for `push`, but still I advise against it.  If you want to keep your `all`, I'd at least recommend setting the `url` to something invalid and setting the push URLs via `pushurl`—although I admit I have never tested this setup.)

What you can and should do instead is declare multiple *remotes* (as you did, remote `origin` and remote `backup`) and then declare a *remote group* as described in [the `git remote` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-remote.html).  The default group is named `default`, and if you do not define one, `git remote update` defaults to finding *all* remotes automatically, skipping only those configured with a special "I am not in the default set" flag.

Hence, simply delete the `all` repo and instead of running `git fetch`, run `git remote update` (or `git fetch --all`).  (Or leave `all` in there for pushing, but my OCD still says "don't do that" :-) )

Answer (score 0):

The command `git fetch --all` simply fetches all and updates the current branches seen with `git branch -av`.

Adding `[remote "all"]` to `.git/config` then keeps multiple repos consistent, while allowing individual pushes if necessary.